# Returning a non-const reference causes a binding reference error

Tags: c++

I've implemented a double linked list using weak and smart pointers. The program is working but I have doubts about that `const` in the `getPrev` signature method. If I put  `const` a the end of the method signature it will cause a binding reference error

```
error: binding reference of type 'std::weak_ptr<Node<Integer> >&' to 'const std::weak_ptr<Node<Integer> >' discards qualifiers
         return prev;
```

Wasn't the purpose of that `const` to mark `*this` as `const` ? The return type is non-const for my understanding.

Here is the code, `main.cpp`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

class Integer {
private:
    int number;
public:
    Integer(int number) : number(number) {}

    int get() { return number; }

};

int main() {

    DoubleLinkedList<Integer> list;
    list.insert(Integer(1));
    list.insert(Integer(2));
    list.insert(Integer(3));
    list.insert(Integer(4));
    list.insert(Integer(5));


    return 0;
}
```

`DoubleLinkedList.h`

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Node {
private:
    T data;
    std::weak_ptr<Node> prev;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
public:
    Node(): data(0) {}

    Node(const T &object) : data(object) {};

    T getData() const {
        return data;
    }

    void setData(T data) {
        Node::data = data;
    }

    std::weak_ptr<Node> &getPrev() const {
        return prev;
    }

    void setPrev(const std::weak_ptr<Node> &prev) {
        Node::prev = prev;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Node> &getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    void setNext(const std::shared_ptr<Node> &next) {
        Node::next = next;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class DoubleLinkedList {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> header;
    std::weak_ptr<Node<T>> trailer;
    int size;
public:

    DoubleLinkedList() : size(0) {}

    void insert(const T &value) {
        auto node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);

        if (size++ == 0) {
            header = node;
        } else {
            auto last = trailer.lock();
            last->getNext() = node;
            node->getPrev() = last;
        }
        trailer = node;
    }


};
```

Comment: "Wasn't the purpose of that const to mark *this as const ?" You are absolutely right. "The return type is non-const for my understanding". You're right once again. And you can't convert `const` to a `non-const` like that. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You should use `unique_ptr` here! Take a look on [this coll cppcon talk](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: every other post here consists of list implementations, why is this a thing? Is it a frequent homework task?

Comment: @StackDanny Yes, it is.

Comment: A reference is not another syntax for a pointer, a reference doesn't actually exist, it literally binds to some other variable at compile time. That other variable, a member of a const class (when *this is const), is also const.

Comment: Why is `auto node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);` generating a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are inside a `const` method, all the data members are considered `const`.

That is, inside this function:

```
std::weak_ptr<Node> &getPrev() const
```

you can imagine the member variables like this:

```
const T data;
const std::weak_ptr<Node> prev;
const std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
```

It should be clear that you cannot return a non-const reference to a const object:

```
const int x;

int& getX()
{
  return x; // error
}
```

The reference would allow you to modify `x` even though it is `const`, so this is forbidden (formally: a non-const reference cannot bind to a const object).

Inside a `const` member function of `Node`, `prev` is a `const std::weak_ptr<Node>`, so a `std::weak_ptr<Node>&` cannot bind to it for the exact same reason.

---

It appears that within `insert` you do intend to modify `node` (by changing its `prev` value), in which case the `getPrev` function should not be const (because you intend to modify the object). But this kind of access should probably be reserved for the `DoubleLinkedList` and not some arbitrary outside user. It then becomes a question of interface design: Which parts of your code are implementation details and how those should be hidden from users? Which parts are the interface that users should interact with (with minimal opportunity for breaking things)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I'm just overusing const references, I always try to deisgn my classes to avoid copies. Anyway, if I declare the `node` inside the `insert` function as `const auto& node = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(value);` I can still do the assignment `node->getPrev() = last;`. Shouldn't that be forbidden?

Comment: So, in the second part of your answer are you telling me that it is unnecessary to work by reference since user can only use the `insert` method of the `list` and cannot access the nodes in the list, but when then references should be strictly used? How can one tell if `T` will create huge objects and make expensive copies in terms of memory usage?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro 1. Yes that was not clearly worded by me. Doing `node->getPrev() = last` when `getPrev` returns by value would assign to a temporary value and immediately discard it - I'll remove that part. 2. Whether `T` will create huge objects is irrelevant here. I also did not say that you should never use references. The solution is to not make `getPrev()` a `const` member function. I was discussing the implications of doing this - do users of `DoubleLinkedList` ever get to see a `Node`? In that case it would be extremely dangerous to leave this function public...

Comment: So from your point of view I should get copies inside the `insert` function?
Given that when in the signature is specified `const`, then why I can still do that assignment? Shouldn't be the returned reference `const`?